# I have a Dart StreamSubscription with a pause operation inside onData. Is it possible for an event to start in between the callback and the pause?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, dart-async

I'm trying to get the callbacks to start and resolve synchronously.

```
fiveSeconds() async {
  print("Start fiveSeconds");
  print("1");
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  print("2");
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  print("3");
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  print("4");
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  print("5");
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  print("End fiveSeconds");
}

twoSeconds() async {
  print("Start twoSeconds");
  print("1");
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  print("2");
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  print("End twoSeconds");
}


profileStreamSubscription.onData((message) async {
      profileStreamSubscription.pause();
      if (message == "send") {
        await fiveSeconds();
        profileStreamSubscription.resume();
      }
      if (message == "send2") {
        await twoSeconds();
        profileStreamSubscription.resume();
      }
    });
```

Output for this function should be something like this:

Call fiveSeconds, call twoSeconds, they resolve in order synchronously.

```
Start fiveSeconds
1
2
3
4
5
End fiveSeconds
Start twoSeconds
1
2
End twoSeconds
```

Not this, vv which is what a StreamSubscription without pause() or resume() would return:

Call fiveSeconds, call twoSeconds, they resolve simultaneously.

```
Start fiveSeconds
Start twoSeconds
1
1
2
2
End twoSeconds
3
4
5
End fiveSeconds
```

Hypothetically could an onData event happen between
`profileStreamSubscription.onData((message) async {` and `profileStreamSubscription.pause();` starting another event before the pause operation happens?

That would return something like this:

Call fiveSeconds, twoSeconds interrupts fiveSeconds before it is paused, resolves synchronously but in the wrong order.

```
Start twoSeconds
1
2
End twoSeconds
Start fiveSeconds
1
2
3
4
5
End fiveSeconds
```

Comment: tried `Stream.asyncMap` ? the docs say: *"Creates a new stream with each data event of this stream asynchronously mapped to a new event.

This acts like map, except that convert may return a Future, and in that case, this stream waits for that future to complete before continuing with its result."*

Comment: Thanks! I haven't tried that yet, but that is a good suggestion. I think I found a solution to my specific problem using StreamQueue from the [async](https://pub.dev/packages/async/install) package. I do want to know whether it's possible to insert a call to on data between starting the call and pausing the stream if anyone knows.